# Python: multiple super classes only triggered 1 __init__ function, why?

Tags: python, linux, class, inheritance, super

I've got a simple test program like this:

```
__metaclass__=type
class b1:
    def __init__(s):
        print "world"
class b2:
    def __init__(s):
        print "hello"
class d(b1,b2):
    def __init__(s):
        super(d,s).__init__()
obj=d()
```

I expect that "d" construting will print out both "b1" and "b2" base classes "**init**" content, and thus I'll see "world hello"

But actually the result was just "world".
I'm using python2.4.5

Any error in my understanding?

Comment: You have to consistently use ``super(...).__init__()`` in ALL of your classes' constructors for this to work right.

Comment: This is python 2 and old style classes?

Comment: The issue is covered in [How does Python's super work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance), especially [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310777/642070) that shows how to do cooperative subclassing. Add `super` calls to your first two classes and it starts working as you want.